# Extract categorical information from pandas DataFrame columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe with columns that encode in their name some categorical information. I would like to extract that information into its own column.
Let's take an example:

Input:

```
pd.DataFrame({'Summits_March': [10, 20, 30], 
              'Summits_April': [40, 50, 60]})

      Summits_March Summits_April
0       10            40
1       20            50
2       30            60
```

Desired output:

```
pd.DataFrame({'Summits': [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60], 
              'Month': ['March', 'March', 'March', 'April', 'April', 'April']})
    Summits Month
0   10      March
1   20      March
2   30      March
3   40      April
4   50      April
5   60      April
```

Comment: `df.rename(columns=lambda x: x.removeprefix('Summits_')).melt(var_name='Month', value_name='Summits')`